# Línea 10: 'Footer' no está definido react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx

No entiendo porque me dice que <Footer/? no esta definido? en estas lineas de codigo

```
    import React, { Component }  from 'react';
    import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar';
    import Layout from '../../hocs/layouts/layout';

    function Home(){
        return(
            <Layout>
                <Navbar/>
                Home 
                <Footer/>
            </Layout>
       )
   }
   export default Home
```

Comment: Hola buenos dias! No has importado el componente Footer

Comment: Gracias Emanuek. por la respuesta! me fue muy util